# Unable to get the query string data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, request, query-string

I am trying to get two query string parameters from JavaScript to the controller. Here is the code:

### JavaScript

```
var startDate = "",
    enddate = "";

var startDate = $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, $("#startDate").datepicker('getDate'));
var enddate = $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, $("#endDate").datepicker('getDate'));

if (startDate != "" || enddate != "") {
  window.location = `${window.location.href}/Index?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${enddate}`;

}
```

### C#

```
public IActionResult Index([FromQuery(Name = "startDate")] string startDate = "", [FromQuery(Name = "endDate")] string endDate = "") 
{    
}
```

The controller gets called, and the first parameter is fin but the second parameter gets a messed up version of the URL. Here is a picture. I am having a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong.

JavaScript Values

[image]

C# values

[image]

Comment: What are the values of `startDate` and `endDate` in javascript? Also, why are you declaring the variables twice in JS? Also, using just `[FromQuery]` should be enough

Comment: What is the value of `window.location.href` in the JavaScript?

Comment: Updated with picures

Comment: The double decleration was a typo when i built the question here on stackowerflow...

Comment: I change the parameter names, so both JavaScript and C# the parameters are called "startDate" and "endDate"

Answer (score 3):

From what you've posted it seems likely that `windows.location.href` is the problem and you are concatenating onto values which already exist in the URL. For example if your href was

```
http://www.somesite/Index?startDate=1&endate=2
```

Then your concatenated string would be:

```
http://www.somesite/Index?startDate=1&endate=2/Index?startDate=1&endDate=2
```

and your values would be:

```
startDate: 1
endDate: 2/Index/startDate=1
```

To solve the problem you could try using `window.location.hostname` instead of href.

**Update**

I think you should make the URL relative:

```
window.location = `/Index?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${enddate}`;
```

Comment: hmm..I see what you mean and it is probably the problem. How would you suggest i use the `.hostname`?

Comment: Where you have `{window.location.href}/Index...` replace it with `{window.location.hostname}/Index...`

Comment: To be super clear, you mean like this `window.location.href = ${window.location.hostname}/Index/?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate};`

Comment: Yes, except with `window.location =` at the beginning.

Comment: The code above gives this URL `http://localhost:55817/localhost/Index/?startDate=2018-07-10&endDate=2018-07-29` tell me what you need, and Ill get it.

Comment: Tried it. It gives the URL i posted above in the comments. The browser cant find the resource

Comment: Tried it and it produced this URL: `http://localhost:55817/Index?startDate=2018-07-09&endDate=2018-07-29` The problem with this is that I got multiple controllers that all have index.cshtml files in the view folder. So the MVC doesnt know wich Index to go to.

Comment: Is this code going to be used on more than one page, if not just hardcode in the controller name before index, if it is you will have to extract the controller name from the url.

Comment: Solved it. But i am still a bit confused which solution down below I should go with. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the "index" in the url. The MVC framework automatically searches for the "index" ActionResult if the Action is missing in the url.

```
window.location = `Salaries?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`;
```

it also works like this:

```
window.location = `?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`;
```